# How to get a sprite to rotate to face the mouse position, using HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/hit-the-target-with-a-deadly-homing-missile/) to create a homing missile in Flash, except I'd like to adapt it to use HTML5 canvas. I'm struggling with getting the sprite to face the direction of the mouse; it rotates but doesn't always face the mouse! I've put up a fiddle so you can see what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mr4Tz/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle value passed to the HTML5 rotate method should be in radians, but you are passing degrees instead.

Based on your example, this should work:

```
var targetX  = mouse.x - missile.x
,   targetY  = mouse.y - missile.y
,   rotation = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX);

context.rotate(rotation);
```